# Input Box VBA , Enter column name instead designation

Tags: vba, excel

i have created a programm that asks for an input Column and then creates an average of the 60 values and then next 60 values and so on. I want that insteas of input of Column(A,B) I will input the variable with which the column have been named , like the column L have been named as Power. so i input power instead of L .

```
Sub Hourlyaverage()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myValue As Variant

    Sheets("DUT1_Test51_excel").Select

    i = 3
    j = 3
    k = 63

    myValue = InputBox("Give Column name to calculate Average eg. A,B")

    Do While Cells(i, 12).Value <> ""
        Set myRange = Range(myValue & i & ":" & myValue & k)
        Cells(j, 20).Value = Application.Average(myRange)
        i = i + 60
        j = j + 1
        k = k + 60
    Loop   
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the column named by the first row? So the title is the name of the column? And how many columns do you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the first row to name the columns then use this. Change colEnd to the amount of columns used. Or get the columns used from vba.

```
Sub Hourlyaverage()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myValue As Variant

    'variables for Column Names
    Dim colEnd As Long, x As Long
    Dim colName As String


    Sheets("DUT1_Test51_excel").Select

    i = 3
    j = 3
    k = 63

    myValue = InputBox("Give Column name to calculate Average eg. A,B")

    'Set columns used
    colEnd = 5

    For x = 1 To colEnd
        If Ucase(Cells(1, x).Value) = Ucase(myValue) Then colName = Right(Left(Cells(1, x).Address, 2), 1)
    Next
    'If column name is not used it will take the value of myValue to see try and use that as a column name incase the user does not use the full name.
    'Tries the first letter incase it was spelt wrong.
    If colName = "" Then colName = Left(UCase(myValue),1)

    Do While Cells(i, 12).Value <> ""
        Set myRange = Range(colName & i & ":" & colName & k)
        Cells(j, 20).Value = Application.Average(myRange)
        i = i + 60
        j = j + 1
        k = k + 60
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: No problem. If it is now answered can you mark it as the answer please?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom function that, given a value, will return you the column:

```
Public Function valueToColumn(ByVal val As String) As String

    valueToColumn = Split(ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z").Find(val).Address, "$")(1)

End Function
```

So all you need to do once the output is got by the user is to turn `myValue` into a column letter with `myValue = valueToColumn(myValue)`.

Please note that:

- The above searches the value in Range `A-Z`. You need to adjust it to your needs.
- The above, if the value is not found, will raise an exception `Variable not set`. You need to manage this with an Error Handler (I let you choose the best according to your needs).

Comment: The code they gave showed that they select a sheet. So why not change sheets("sheet1") to activesheet?